# Не загружается Ubuntu server 20.04 без видеокарты

Tags: ubuntu, grub

Установил Ubuntu server 20.04. Если вынуть видеокарту, система не загружается, а именно не пингуется. Если поставить обратно - все работает, пингуется. CPU не имеет встроенного видео.

Как можно загрузить систему? Я поправил `/etc/default/grub`, как написано в интернетах, затем `update-grub`, ситуация не изменилась. Измененные строки:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="nomodeset"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="text"
GRUB_TERMINAL=console
```

PS. POST проходит 100%. Записи в syslog о процессе загрузки есть. Каких-то ошибок я не нашел. При нажатии на кнопку power запускается процесс остановки демонов, что также видно в сислоге.

Comment: А загрузка-то дальше биоса вообще идёт?

Comment: @andreymal Конечно же нет, там тупо не проходит POST. И если бы к материнке был подключен спикер или колонки, спикер бы пищал три коротких сигнала и один длинный циклично пока не выключишь комп)).

Comment: @andreymal POST проходит. Почему ему не проходить? В BIOS я отключил Halt on error, успешно грузится без всего, кроме видюхи. В логах (syslog) тоже есть, что загружается, и при нажатии на power стопятся демоны, но ... не пингуется. Каких-то ошибок я найти не смог, даже точно не знаю что именно искать.

Comment: добавьте в автозагрузку что-нибудь вроде `while:; do sleep 10; { date; ip a; ip r; } >> ~/log; done` и посмотрите потом, что там с сетью происходит при загрузке без видеокарты.

Comment: Попробуйте поменять на такие `GRUB_TERMINAL_OUTPUT="serial console" 
GRUB_TERMINAL="serial console" 
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=""
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="text nomodeset"` . И что в логах journalctl? ssh или сети